# What the semicolon mean in the src property of this img tag?

Tags: html, image, src

I have a chm ebook, and I decompiled it to html pages. But when I open some html pages with images, the images cannot display in my ArchLinux firefox browser.

When I saw the html source, I found the img tag is:
`<img src="images/08fig02.gif;423615">`, I can find the image `08f8g02.gif` in the images directory, so I delete `;423615`, and the image display well.

But this same page can display well in Firefox on Windows, also display well in Chrome.

So my question is: what this semicolon and the number after it mean?

Comment: Random guess based on Windows shortcut icons: It's referencing a frame number in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But would you please explain more clearly? Why a chm file need this? Is it will do something better?